# Forward subdomain to another dns-server with dnsmasq

Tags: bind, internal-dns, dnsmasq

I have dnsmasq as main dns-server in localnet(192.168.0.14).
It's serve local domain 'example'. Also I have another dns-server(bind9 - 192.168.222.67) that serve domain 'virt.example'
Here part of dnsmasq config:

```
auth-zone=example,192.168.0.14/32
auth-zone=land.example,192.168.0.14/32
server=/example/192.168.0.14

host-record=land.example,192.168.0.14
host-record=host1.example,192.168.0.14
...
host-record=hostN.example,192.168.0.14
...
server=/*.virt.example/192.168.222.67
```

In this configuration server 192.168.0.14 answers on all queries about domain **.example** but returns NXDOMAIN about any host in **virt.example**. In logs I can see that at start all looks fine:

```
Apr 19 12:51:45 dnsmasq[7982]: using nameserver 192.168.222.67#53 for domain *.virt.example (no DNSSEC)
Apr 19 12:51:45 dnsmasq[7982]: using nameserver 192.168.222.67#53 for domain *.virt.example (no DNSSEC)
```

but query was not forwarded correctly

```
Apr 19 12:52:56 dnsmasq[7982]: query[A] vm04-mail.virt.example from 192.168.0.10
Apr 19 12:52:56 dnsmasq[7982]: auth vm04-mail.virt.example is NXDOMAIN
```

bind9 works fine:

```
$ nslookup vm04-mail.virt.example 192.168.222.67
Server:         192.168.222.67
Address:        192.168.222.67#53

Name:   vm04-mail.virt.example
Address: 10.10.10.4
```

Why dnsmasq don't forward query to bind?

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer, but I would try two options to see if it changes anything :
1. change the last line from 
`server=/*.virt.example/192.168.222.67` to 
`server=/virt.example/192.168.222.67` as this seems to be the way it is written in the man page of dns-masq.

2. I'd also try to comment out the first line :
`#auth-zone=example,192.168.0.14/32`
To see if the `auth-zone` took priority over the server directive on the `virt` subdomain.